# AttributeError: 'Ui_WizardPage' object has no attribute 'lcdTemp' in pyqt5

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, pyqt5

Hello i am making an application in pyqt 5 that can show a counter in a lcd display. I want to run a counter that will run simulationeously and the counter will be displayed in the gui

I have write the following code for the application:`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

counter = 0

from threading import Timer




class RepeatedTimer(object):
def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
    self._timer     = None
    self.interval   = interval
    self.function   = function
    self.args       = args
    self.kwargs     = kwargs
    self.is_running = False
    self.start()

def _run(self):
    self.is_running = False
    self.start()
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

def start(self):
    if not self.is_running:
        self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
        self._timer.start()
        self.is_running = True

def stop(self):
    self._timer.cancel()
    self.is_running = False



class Ui_WizardPage(object):
def setupUi(self, WizardPage):
    WizardPage.setObjectName("WizardPage")
    WizardPage.resize(574, 365)
    self.onBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(WizardPage)
    self.onBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 70, 171, 111))
    self.onBtn.setObjectName("onBtn")
    self.lcdTemp = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(WizardPage)
    self.lcdTemp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 260, 171, 71))
    self.lcdTemp.setObjectName("lcdTemp")
    self.lcdTemp.display(counter)


    self.retranslateUi(WizardPage)
    self.onBtn.clicked.connect(self.opm)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(WizardPage)

def retranslateUi(self, WizardPage):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    WizardPage.setWindowTitle(_translate("WizardPage", "WizardPage"))
    self.onBtn.setText(_translate("WizardPage", "ON"))


def opm(self):
    #time.sleep(1)

    GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
    if GPIO.input(12) == GPIO.HIGH:
        print('on')


obj1 = Ui_WizardPage()



if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
WizardPage = QtWidgets.QWizardPage()
ui = Ui_WizardPage()
ui.setupUi(WizardPage)
WizardPage.show()
print('off')


def hello(name):

    global counter
    #print("Hello %s!" % name)

    counter = counter + 1
    print(counter)
    #self.lcdTemp.display(counter)
    obj1.lcdTemp.display(counter)
print("starting...")
rt = RepeatedTimer(1, hello,  name="World")  # it auto-starts, no need of rt.start()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ignore the indents it is done correctly in the program

The following error comes

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_WizardPage' object has no attribute 'lcdTemp'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to [follow the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions and always remember to check that the code you post is [well formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) (for instance, your code has a lot of indentation issues). Finally, files generated by pyuic should **never** be manually modified, doing it is considered bad practice; read more about the correct usage on the [official guidelines](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)

Comment: please improve your indentation, in python is very important